# Python3 missing exception when looping

Tags: python-3.x, exception, error-handling

I have to define an attribute in a class and I would like to manage error in the most pythonic way.

Here is the code I have tried so far. I can't figure out why I can not "reach" the exception in the following code.

```py
# global variable to be used in the example

my_dict = {"key1": {"property": 10}, "key2": {}}

class Test(object):
    @property
    def my_attribute(self):
        try:
            return self._my_attribute
        except AttributeError:
            self._my_attribute = {}
            for key, value in my_dict.items():
                print(key)
                self._my_attribute[key] = value['property']
        except Exception:
            print('error')
            # I would like to manage my error here with a log or something
            print("I am not reaching here")
        finally:
            return self._my_attribute


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().my_attribute
```

I expected to reach the Exception case in the second iteration of the for loop since it is a KeyError ("key2" has no "property"). But it just passes by it. In this example, if the script is run, it does not print "I am not reaching here". Could anyone explain why I am seeing this wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: "But it did not" Then what did it do?

Comment: Hopefully this change is a reproducible example. I also edit the question. Answering the second comment: I assume it was going to enter Exception clause, but it "ignored" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential `KeyError` in `self._my_attribute[key] = value['property']` is not covered by the `except Exception` block. Once it is raised the `finally` block is executed (as a matter of fact the `finally` block is *always* executed, regardless of an exception being raised or even handled). This can be easily verified by using a step-by-step debugger or with a simple `print('finally')` inside the `finally` block.

This is (among other reasons) why `try` blocks should be as minimal as possible. If you know that line might raise a `KeyError` then explicitly `try-except` it:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(key)
    try:
        self._my_attribute[key] = value['property']
    except KeyError as e:
        print('Key ', e, 'does not exist')
```